# Can't get requests and mandrill to work in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, python-requests, aws-lambda, mandrill

I'm following [a tutorial](https://gist.github.com/bstancil/27bcc64c81df311e436fce6441c067cc) on using AWS Lambda.

I set up an AWS Lambda function using the default code. Now I need to upload a ZIP containing my dependencies.  Every time I do so, I get the following error

```
This function contains external libraries. Uploading a new file will override these libraries.
```

Uh..ok?

So here's what I'm doing:

1. Create a new directory
2. Navigate to said directory
3. `pip install -t /path/to/my_directory requests mandrill`
4. Open up Explorer and navigate to the directory
5. Highlight everything in the directory* and compress, creating `Archive.zip`
6. Upload `Archive.zip`
7. Stare at error with no comprehension.

I've tried renaming my Handler, under 'Configuration' to `Archive.lambda_handler` and `archive.lambda_handler` but it's the same error.

What should I try next?  Is there a better tutorial to start with?

**Edit** 
I should be clear, the tutorial I'm following leads me to believe I can upload the ZIP file and then navigate back to the in-line editor (via Code > Code entry type).  But after uploading, `In-line editor` is no longer available in the dropdown.

*For the curious 13 folders (`__pycache__, certifi, certifi-201.., chardet, chardet-3.0.4.dist-info, docopt-0.4.0.dist-info, idna, idna-2.6.dist-info, mandrill-1...., requests, requests-2..., urllib3, urllib3-1.22.dist-info`) plus two python files (`docopt`, `mandrill`).

Comment: Which file contains your `lambda_handler`?

Comment: You handler in your configuration should be `module_name.lambda_handler` not directory name ("archive").

Comment: Additionally, *"This function contains external libraries. Uploading a new file will override these libraries"* isn't an error.  That message is always shown when the function contains external libraries.  Click the Test button, next, maybe?